# I want to copy column D:I,K,O,AG,AH,AA but it currently copies D:AH

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

```
Sub AutofillData()

    Dim wkbkSource As Workbook

    Dim strPath As String
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim c As Range
    Dim wkbkTarget As Workbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    strPath = "\\temp\"

    Set wkbkA = ThisWorkbook
    Set wkbkB = Workbooks.Open(strPath & Range("E8").Value)

        Set myRange = wkbkA.Sheets("Stand-up Request").Range("B13:B25")

        offs = 0
        For Each c In myRange

            i = c.Value

            wkbkB.Worksheets("Main Data").Range("D" & i & ":AH" & i).Copy

            wkbkA.Sheets("Stand-up Request").Range("C13").Offset(offs, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            offs = offs + 1

       On Error Resume Next

        Next

     wkbkB.Close savechanges:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: i used the on error next becuase i keep getting the runtime error 1004 becuase of this line wkbkB.Worksheets("Main Data").Range("D" & i & ":AH" & i).Copy
 i have checked the names and everything is correct.

Comment: Please see [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to expand your question into something that we can better use, including formatting. Also update your question with your latest comment so people looking at your question don't need to hunt for additional information in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind the column order, you should only change one row:

`wkbkB.Worksheets("Main Data").Range("D" & i & ":I" & i & ",K" & i & ",O" & i & ",AG" & i & ",AH" & i & ",AA" & i).Copy`

Note that this way AA gets pasted before AG. If you mind the column order, you should split your range and copy/paste them separately:

```
wkbkB.Worksheets("Main Data").Range("D" & i & ":I" & i & ",K" & i & ",O" & i & ",AG" & i & ",AH" & i).Copy

wkbkA.Sheets("Stand-up Request").Range("C13").Offset(offs, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

wkbkB.Worksheets("Main Data").Range("AA" & i).Copy

wkbkA.Sheets("Stand-up Request").Range("C13").Offset(offs, 10).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
```

Note that this is a static code, if you change the columns to copy, you should also set the column value of the second paste's offset accordingly. If you want a dynamic code, you should create another range object that you will copy and you can get the dimensions of that range.

Also it might be better avoiding copy/paste altogether, using code like:

`wkbkA.Sheets("Stand-up Request").Range("C13").Offset(offs, 0).Resize(1, 6).Value = wkbkB.Worksheets("Main Data").Range("D" & i & ":I" & i).Value`

But it needs to be done for each sub-range, so it gets more complicated.

Also note that your code worked fine for me on ActiveSheet without `On Error Resume Next`, so you better check your code again :)